# how to customize login page for shibboleth idp

Tags: shibboleth

I would like to customize the login page and I'm trying to follow the shibboleth wiki, but I'm not sure where to find " src/main/webapp/login.jsp within your IdP distribution package" in order to modify it. My shibboleth resides in /opt/shibboleth-idp, but I don't have a src folder in there. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(sorry this is two months late, but...)*

the files for login are not stored inside your shibboleth-idp directory. (well, they're sorta in there...rolled into the java war file.)

somewhere, there should be a directory that was used to build your shibboleth-idp instance.  many times i've seen it in the same folder as the shibboleth-idp folder, but it doesn't have to be.  so since yours is /opt/shibboleth-idp, it might be at /opt/shibboleth-identityprovider-*version.number*.  if not, use the find command as already suggested, but maybe try something like

`find / -name 'shibboleth-identityprovider*' -ls 2>/dev/null`

unless someone built it off-box, that folder should exist somewhere.  inside there is the src directory where login.jsp resides.

the install script the shib doc tells you to run after making your changes is at the top level of that shibboleth-identityprovider-*version.number* folder too (install.sh for unix).  when you run the install script, you tell it where to put the idp files (in your case, /opt/shibboleth-idp).

also, before running the install script, it's a good idea to back up your conf directory.  you might accidentally tell the install script to overwrite it.  or it might do it even if you told it not to (bug in some versions).

Comment: Thanks I resolved it a while back, but yeah they're in a WAR file which I had to unzip and rezip after making changes.

Answer (score 3):

For IdP version 3, you can customize by changing the files in the "views" directory.  These are Apache Velocity templates, and you can make changes that become active without having to rebuild the war file.

Comment: and how to customize this in a 'future-proof' manner? is there something like `edit-webapp` for those views, too?

Comment: The `views` directory is the place for this, as it does not get updated during upgrades just like the `edit-webapp` directory.
Reference: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/Configuration#Configuration-InstallationLayout

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with the Linux find command:

```
find /opt/shibboleth-idp/ -name login.jsp
```